# SSL Certificate Verification fails when logging into Azure Container Registry

Tags: python, azure, ssl, https

I am new to Azure and am trying to get the command line working from my computer (mac OS). I installed the azure-cli via homebrew and when I execute `az login`, I get the following error:

```
Error occurred in request., SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tenants?api-version=2016-06-01 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.25/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 441, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.25/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1806, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.25/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1546, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.25/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]
```

I have tried the following:

```
export ADAL_PYTHON_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
export AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=1
```

as per this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2267

and that lets me log in, but when I execute `az acr login --name <registry name>` I get a similar error again:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='registryName.azurecr.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.25/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 441, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.25/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1806, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.25/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1546, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.25/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck with this? Having similar problem requesting objects from azure

Comment: Having the same issue. I think this happens when you are behind a proxy

Answer (score 1):

Trying setting REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE as mentioned in the doc here: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/use_cli_effectively.md#working-behind-a-proxy

Comment: try to avoid to post links

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the Python library doesn't perform the handshake properly.  Judging by the errors, OpenSSL doesn't seem to want to trust the request when it is made by the Python script.

https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api.html This site gives information about the OpenSSL library.  The Python scripts don't seem to be implementing the SSL functions correctly.